# Keras - Tune a sequential model by testing all the possible hyper parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, sequential, hyperparameters

I'm working on a simple Keras sequential model and I'm trying to test different combinations of hyperparameters but is there a way to try all the possible combinations of these hyperparameters automatically which provides me the best combinations?

Here's my keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
input_neurons = 70
model.add(LSTM(input_neurons, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))
optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00134)
model.compile(loss=loss_func, optimizer=optimizer)
history = model.fit(
     train_X,
     train_y,
     epochs=200, batch_size=72,
     validation_data=(test_X, test_y),
     verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try [hyperas](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) and[talos](https://github.com/autonomio/talos) for example, but there are other too. Just look up automatic hyperparameter optimization and you will surely find more results.

Comment: @lgna , can you put an example according to my code?

Comment: just check the links, they provide exactly what you ask

Comment: it's giving me e error as: `TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got tuple` and pointing to the `trials=Trials()`

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it solved your question. For new questions, update the question or put a new one.